# How to inspect Flutter website in Browser

Tags: flutter, automated-tests

I am trying to inspect the Flutter website to add automation on it using **Python**.

This website is available for **Android**, **iOS** & also on **Web**.
Now trying to inspect the website, but not able to select the element/component.

[image: WEBSITE Screenshot]

> *Not able to inspect the component/element on the browser*

Please suggest any solution for **how to inspect the Flutter Website**?
I tried to search on different blogs but did not get the proper lead to start this. Please help me.

**Update:**

> Can it be possible to inspect from the browser only because the code is not available.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible with the flutter inspector. See: https://docs.flutter.dev/tools/devtools/inspector

I"m not sure what you use to run your app, but you might want to consider Android Studio for doing so.
Run the app in debug mode, then when you are in the debug tab, just press the blue icon in the task bar named 'Open flutter DevTools'.

Good luck!

Edit: flutter draws it's components on the canvas in most cases (depending on the render mode, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/web/renderers), so inspecting elements like in regular websites doesn't really work the same unfortunately.